# How to use Laravel Package LandLord

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im still fairly new to Laravel and have worked through some of the fundamental laracasts.  Now I'm starting my first laravel project but I am stuck on how to use my first package "Landlord".  Basically I need a setup for Multi-Tenants in my application.  I have a company table and a user table, the user table has a company_id column.  When a company registers it successfully creates the company and attaches the company_id to the user.

I assume Landlord is the best way to implement a multi-tenant application so I worked through the installation instructions and now I have it included in my app.

However the first line in the USAGE section says:
IMPORTANT NOTE: Landlord is stateless. This means that when you call addTenant(), it will only scope the current request.

> Make sure that you are adding your tenants in such a way that it
>   happens on every request, and before you need Models scoped, like in a
>   middleware or as part of a stateless authentication method like OAuth.

And it looks like I need to attach a the `Landlord::addTenant('tenant_id', 1);` facade.

This may be a pretty simple answer I am overlooking but where is the best place to to use `addTenant` and do I have to redeclare it with every controller or model?  Should I attach it when the user signs in, use it in my routes or use as a middleware?  If it is a middleware is the following correct in order to pull the company_id from the current user and use it with `addTenant`?

Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    $tenantId = Auth::user()->tenant_id;

    Landlord::addTenant('tenant_id', $tenantId);

    return $next($request);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my middleware (MultiTenant.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MultiTenant
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {        
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $tenantId = Auth::user()->company_id;

            Landlord::addTenant('company_id', $tenantId); // Different column name, but same concept
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['multitenant']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    //Clients
    Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');
});
```

My Client.php Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\BelongsToTenants;

class Client extends Model
{
    use BelongsToTenants;
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'organization',
    ];

}
```

https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord#user-content-usage

Comment: If all your tables with tenants' data has `tenant_id` key, then they will all be queried with global additional global scoped `WHERE` `tenant_id = ID` (of course if they have `BelongsToTenants` trait). And yes, middleware is the best place for adding tenants, imho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While just one option, I also went the `middleware` route. I saw it as an easy way to implement it.

I added the `middleware` to my `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['landlord']], function () {
    // Your routes
});
```

And my `landlord middleware` looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{        
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $tenantId = Auth::user()->company_id;

        Landlord::addTenant('company_id', $tenantId); // Different column name, but same concept
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then I just add the `trait` to the models that I want scoped:

```
use HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\BelongsToTenant;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use BelongsToTenant;
}
```

**Update**

Also, make sure in your `config/app.php` file you have added `landlord` to the `providers` array:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\LandlordServiceProvider::class
    // ...
],
```

And to the `aliases` array:

```
'aliases' => [

    // ...
    'Landlord'   => HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\Facades\Landlord::class,
    // ...
],
```

Then finally `composer dump-autoload` when completed to refresh the autoloading.

Comment: I was headed in the right direction.  I had done everything you suggested here but I get the error `Trait 'HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\BelongsToTenant' not found` from my model.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Derek Yep, you are! Did you update your `app.php` config file with Landlord info?

Comment: Yes, I followed the setup instructions on the github page.  Here is a screenshot of my bootstrap/app.php file: http://imgur.com/a/gdtB6

Comment: @Derek Sorry, I was talking about your `config/app.php` file. Let me update my answer to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: Hmm, `composer dump-autoload` is what I needed to get passed the above error but now (using your example for the middleware file I get this: `FatalErrorException in MultiTenant.php line 24:
Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Landlord' not found` **Note I have my middleware named MultiTenant instead of Landlord but I dont think that matters ** . I updated my question to show my middleware, route and test model

Comment: @Derek That error is saying that it can't find your `Landlord` class. If you added it to the `aliases` array as shown above, make sure you import it at the top of your `MultiTenant.php` file: `use Landlord;`